# Convert integer to byte but do not overflow

Tags: c#, .net, casting, integer, byte

How can I convert/cast an integer value to a byte value in C# but do not wrap around or throw an exception? What I'm looking for is some sort of `bool byte.TryConvert(int i, out b)` method.

I tried `Convert.ToByte` and direct casts.

```
byte b = Convert.ToByte(257); // throws OverflowException
byte b = (byte)257; // results in 1
byte b = (byte)(-1); // results in 255
```

Or do I have to "reverse-cast" (for lack of a better word) the byte to an int and compare it to the original value?

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but what stops you from just checking if your int is greater than 255 before doing a cast?

Comment: What is your intended result? (and surely the result of that cast from 256 (pre-edit) is 0, not 1?)

Comment: @MarcGravell: intended result is `null` (for my usecase). A method which returns true if casting/conversion was successful and false for failed conversions would be best (if such a function already exists in the .NET framework).

Comment: It's not obvious from your question what result you want for the cases were the integer is outside the range 0 - 255.

Comment: @knittl `null` is not a valid value for `byte`, so you can't do that; you'd need to use `byte?` or similar

Comment: @MarcGravell: yes, I understand that. In my concrete use case I have in fact a nullable byte type. That should not matter for this question though if we compress it down to "is there such a method as `bool byte.TryConvert(int i, out b)`?

Comment: @knittl I've edited my answer to include a sample function that does not use `byte?`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In my concrete use case I have in fact a nullable byte type.
>   ...
>   is there such a method as bool byte.TryConvert(int i, out b)?

No. You would have to do something like:

```
byte? result = (value >= byte.MinValue && value <= byte.MaxValue)
             ? (byte)value : (byte?)null;
```

Comment: "is there such a method as bool byte.TryConvert(int i, out b)?" - there is now. :-)

Comment: Looks good (not as contrived as my solution), thanks! :) why cast value to byte and not a nullable byte? Is there a difference between `? (byte?)value : null` and `? (byte)value : (byte?)null`? I know that .NET sometimes generates weird (iow inefficient) IL code when nullable primitive types are involved.

Comment: Yup, just verified with LINQPad that two casts will result in less IL instructions than the version with a single cast to `byte?`

Answer (score 2):

Write the method yourself.  Check the value of the int.  If it is in range, return true and assign it to the out parameter with a direct cast.  If not, return false, setting the out parameter to zero.

Downvoter please comment.

EDIT here's my solution; unlike Marc Gravell's, it does not introduce nullability:

```
public bool TryToByte(int value, out byte result)
{
    var success = value >= byte.MinValue && value <= byte.MaxValue;
    result = (byte)(success ? value : 0);
    return success;
}
```

Comment: @Alex I did not include an example because it seemed to me that this was a bit of a "please write my code for me" question.

Comment: Ah, more downvotes.  I've now added the method I had in mind when I wrote this answer.